# SFTP Batch Process

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I am developing the CLP to fetch the file from the remote host. Connection method – SFTP
My CLP is as below,

```
    0007.00              DCL        VAR(&USER    )    TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10)   
    0008.00              DCL        VAR(&HOST    )    TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(100)  
    0009.00              DCL        VAR(&CMD     )    TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(500)  
    0010.00              DCL        VAR(&PORT    )    TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10)   
    0011.00              CHGVAR     VAR(&USER) VALUE('user id')          
    0012.00              CHGVAR     VAR(&HOST) VALUE('server name')       
    0013.00              CHGVAR     VAR(&PORT) VALUE('11422')  
    ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(SFTP_USER) VALUE(&USER) REPLACE(*YES)
    ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(SFTP_HOST) VALUE(&HOST) REPLACE(*YES)
    CHGVAR     VAR(&CMD) +                                   
    VALUE('PATH=$PATH:/QOpenSys/usr/bin;scp +   
    -v -2 -P11422 +                             
     $SFTP_USER@$SFTP_HOST:/dock/out/ECRCGB04.tx+
     t /home/sftpadp')                           
    ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_QSH_CMD_OUTPUT) +                  
    VALUE('FILEAPPEND=/home/sftpadp/sftplog.txt') +
      REPLACE(*YES)                                  
    ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_QSH_CMD_ESCAPE_MSG) VALUE(Y) +     
    REPLACE(*YES)                                            
    QSH CMD(&CMD)                                           
    MONMSG MSGID(QSH0000) EXEC(DO)                          
    SNDMSG MSG('File transfer failed! See /tmp/sftplog.txt')
    TOUSR(AS417)                                            
    ENDDO                                                   
    ENDPGM
```

But when I run the program getting below log..

```
    Executing: program /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/SC1/OpenSSH/openssh-  4.7p1/bin/ssh      host 217.108.10.34
    OpenSSH_5.8p1
    debug1: Reading configuration data      /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/SC1/OpenSSH/openssh-4.7p1/etc/ssh_config 
    debug1: Connecting to server [server] port 11422. 
    debug1: Connection established. 
    debug1: identity file /home/sftpadp/.ssh/id_rsa type 1 
    debug1: identity file /home/sftpadp/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 
    debug1: identity file /home/sftpadp/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 
    debug1: identity file /home/sftpadp/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 
    debug1: identity file /home/sftpadp/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 
    debug1: identity file /home/sftpadp/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0
    debug1: no match: SFTP Server 
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0 
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received 
    debug1: Entering the function :kex_choose_conf

    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none 
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent 
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent 
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY 
    debug1: Server host key: DSA  3a:fd:bd:63:17:b8:55:9b:bd:82:e6:1e:84:7a:f7:50 
    debug1: Host '[217.108.10.34]:11422' is known and matches the DSA host key. 
    debug1: Found key in /home/sftpadp/.ssh/known_hosts:1 
    debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent 
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received 
    debug1: Roaming not allowed by server 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 
    SSH Server supporting SFTP and SCP
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey 
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/sftpadp/.ssh/id_rsa 
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/sftpadp/.ssh/id_dsa 
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/sftpadp/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
    debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

It seems that public key validation problem. But the process is working fine interactively.
Can anyone help.

Comment: How is SFTP involved here? It looks like you're running scp.

Comment: Yes. I tried SFTP but its not working so used scp.